# GWTP Gatekeeper

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp

I do someexample from GWTP

http://blog.arcbees.com/2015/10/27/gwtp-beginners-tutorial-toaster-launcher-part-2/#Gatekeeper

```
@DefaultGatekeeper
public class LoggedInGatekeeper implements Gatekeeper {
    private CurrentUser currentUser;

    @Inject
    public LoggedInGatekeeper(CurrentUser currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canReveal() {
        return currentUser.isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

Here we give access if user is login.

Is it possible to find out which page (NameToken) wants to go by? And whether to give him a right, depending on the permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just inject a `PlaceManager` into your `LoggedInGatekeeper` and call [getCurrentPlaceRequest](http://arcbees.github.io/GWTP/javadoc/apidocs/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/proxy/PlaceManager.html#getCurrentPlaceRequest()) and then compare it your `NameToken`. Something along these lines:

```
@DefaultGatekeeper
public class LoggedInGatekeeper implements Gatekeeper {
    private CurrentUser currentUser;
    private PlaceManager placeManager;

    @Inject
    public LoggedInGatekeeper(CurrentUser currentUser, PlaceManager placeManager) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
        this.placeManager = placeManager;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canReveal() {
        PlaceRequest request = placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest();
        if (request.hasSameNameToken('someNameToken') {

           return currentUser.isLoggedIn();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```